# VB.net decrypt rinjdael-128 encrypted string

Tags: encryption, aes, vb.net-2010

I am writing a VB.Net app that reads and decrypts the response from a JSON web service. I have the secret passphrase and I am able to decrypt the encrypted string without a problem using online decryption tools and such. However, I have yet to be able to figure out how to write the code in VB.Net.

Below is an example of the encrypted string returned from the JSON web service:

```
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
```

Key:

> d40da16b8bc6b5e33ef3ae5f704edb2b

I know that it is Rinjdael-128 encryption and that the string needs to be Base64 decoded. I just cant seem figure out the code to do it in VB.Net. I have tried a number of examples onlinethe likes, but nothing I do gets the expected result. The expected will be a JSON should be a JSON formatted string.

Here is my latest attempt that has failed miserably:

```
Dim rmt As RijndaelManaged = New RijndaelManaged()

   Using rmt
       rmt.KeySize = 128
       rmt.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
       rmt.Padding = PaddingMode.ISO10126

       Dim ciphertext() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(json)

       Dim plaintext() As Byte = rmt.CreateDecryptor(Convert.FromBase64String(key), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)).TransformFinalBlock(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.Length)

       Dim decryptedtext As String = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plaintext)
                        Console.WriteLine(decryptedtext)
   End Using
```

I would greatly appreciate any insight or help that anyone can offer.

Thanks

Comment: That's a weird padding mode; are you sure it's ISO10126? Could you indicate how your code fails, does it throw a BadPaddingException or such?

Comment: Your key is not base64, it's hexadecimals. Don't call it a passphrase, cause it's not.

Comment: Owlstead- no error, just don't get the resulting string that I should. I don't know that the padding mode is ISO10126. I have tried others (None, PKS, and Zeros) and they didn't change my results at all.

Comment: I know the key is hex. The encrypted string is Base64 encoded.

Comment: `Convert.FromBase64String(key)` assumes the key is base64, not hex

Comment: `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(InitialVector)` is nonsensical.

Comment: Sorry, the code that is above is where I was at when I finally decided to post the question. I was trying anything. The system.Text.Encoding.ASCII part was something I changed just to see what affect it would have. That was not what it started out as.

However, I totally missed that convert.frombase64string(key). I had looked at the code so much I cant believe that I missed that.

Comment: I can not believe that all this time it was simply the Convert.FromBase64String(key) that was tripping me up. I still have an issue with the beggining of the decrypted string not decrypting properly, but the rest of it is working perfectlly now. Many thanks.

Comment: That's the IV that's wrong. Maybe it's hex as well instead of ASCII? Or maybe the IV is prepended to the cipher text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, as most of the time, not so much in the encryption as in the (character) encodings and knowing how the IV and padding is applied. If you correct the encoding of the key, the IV and use the correct padding, then the message should decrypt.

This answer more or less sums up the suggestions in the comments that managed to retrieve the plain text; most importantly the key was in hexadecimals instead of base64.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the help. I cant believe all the time I spent looking for something missing when the entire time it was that I was trying to convert a hex key using convert.frombase64string.

Answer (score 0):

I built this dll a long time ago. It works for Rijndael decryption. I hope this solves your problem:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports Microsoft.Win32

Public Class GateKeeper


    Public Function Decipher(ByVal vstrStringToBeDecrypted As String, ByVal vstrDecryptionKey As String) As String

        Dim bytDataToBeDecrypted() As Byte
        Dim bytTemp() As Byte
        Dim bytIV() As Byte = {121, 241, 10, 1, 132, 74, 11, 39, 255, 91, 45, 78, 14, 211, 22, 62}
        Dim objRijndaelManaged As New RijndaelManaged
        Dim objMemoryStream As MemoryStream
        Dim objCryptoStream As CryptoStream
        Dim bytDecryptionKey() As Byte

        Dim intLength As Integer
        Dim intRemaining As Integer
        Dim intCtr As Integer
        Dim strReturnString As String = String.Empty
        Dim achrCharacterArray() As Char
        Dim intIndex As Integer
        Dim StripNullCharactersFunc As New StringHandler

        bytDataToBeDecrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(vstrStringToBeDecrypted)

        intLength = Len(vstrDecryptionKey)


        If intLength >= 32 Then
            vstrDecryptionKey = Strings.Left(vstrDecryptionKey, 32)
        Else
            intLength = Len(vstrDecryptionKey)
            intRemaining = 32 - intLength
            vstrDecryptionKey = vstrDecryptionKey & Strings.StrDup(intRemaining, "X")
        End If

        bytDecryptionKey = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(vstrDecryptionKey.ToCharArray)

        ReDim bytTemp(bytDataToBeDecrypted.Length)

        objMemoryStream = New MemoryStream(bytDataToBeDecrypted)

        Try

            objCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(objMemoryStream, _
               objRijndaelManaged.CreateDecryptor(bytDecryptionKey, bytIV), _
               CryptoStreamMode.Read)

            objCryptoStream.Read(bytTemp, 0, bytTemp.Length)

            objCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()
            objMemoryStream.Close()
            objCryptoStream.Close()

        Catch

        End Try

        Return StripNullCharactersFunc.StripNullCharacters(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytTemp))

    End Function

End Class



Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class StringHandler

    'lets get rid oof spaces
    Public Function StripNullCharacters(ByVal vstrStringWithNulls As String) As String
        'This function removes spaces from strings

        Dim intPosition As Integer
        Dim strStringWithOutNulls As String

        intPosition = 1
        strStringWithOutNulls = vstrStringWithNulls

        Do While intPosition > 0
            intPosition = InStr(intPosition, vstrStringWithNulls, vbNullChar)

            If intPosition > 0 Then
                strStringWithOutNulls = Left$(strStringWithOutNulls, intPosition - 1) & _
                                  Right$(strStringWithOutNulls, Len(strStringWithOutNulls) - intPosition)
            End If

            If intPosition > strStringWithOutNulls.Length Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        Return strStringWithOutNulls

    End Function

End Class
```